# Is there a way to query for comments in a SQL Server stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am looking to shows documentation steps of my stored procedures. The best way to start this would be to pull all the comments out of my stored procedures. Is there a way to query and return only the comments from my stored procedures?

Answer (score 2):

For comments beginning with "--" you could use [Ngrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) like this:

```
DECLARE @storedproc varchar(8000) =
'-- Some Comments
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Some Comments

SELECT FirstName -- we only need the first name
FROM dbo.Users WHERE Id = @Id;';

SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    lineNumber = row_number() over (ORDER BY d.p),
    wholeLine  = SUBSTRING
               (
                 @storedproc, 
                 d.p+l.d, -- delimiter position + delimiter length
                  isnull(nullif(charindex(char(10), @storedproc, d.p+l.d),0) - (d.p+l.d), l.s+l.d)
               )
  FROM (values (len(@storedproc), 1)) as l(s,d) -- length of the string and delimiter as "inline variables"
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT -(l.d) UNION ALL -- 0 would be fine too; I'm using -(l.d) to keep the formula uniform
    SELECT ng.position
    FROM dbo.NGrams8K(@storedproc, l.d) as ng
    WHERE token = char(10)
  ) as d(p) -- delimiter.position
) split
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (SUBSTRING(wholeLine, charindex('--', wholeLine), 8000))) txt(comment)
WHERE txt.comment LIKE '%--%';
```

**Returns:**

```
lineNumber  wholeLine                                         comment
----------  ----------------------------------------------    -----------------------
1           -- Some Comments                                  -- Some Comments
4           -- Some Comments                                  -- Some Comments
6           SELECT FirstName  -- we only need the first name  -- we only need the first name
```

For procs longer than 8,000 characters using [NGrams2B](https://github.com/AlanBurstein/SQL-Library/blob/master/dbo.NGrams2B.sql) and change each instance of 8000 in my code to the length of your input string.